# When to create a separate model as other class attribute in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite

I have a 'Book' model. *Publisher's name* and *Genre*(Thriller, Horror, Fantasy etc.) are required to create a new Book.

I was wondering, when should I create new table and model, for example for the genre, so that I would access book's genres with *book.genres*, and when it's ok just to use a simple string variable for defining an attribute?

I was thinking that it depends whether I want to access different book's by publisher's/genre's name, however it can be done using sql queries anyway, can't it?

I need some clarification on that matter. When to create a seperate model and table?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing Rails-specific or even database-specific about your question. Instead, you should be approaching it from an object-oriented design standpoint - and the answer is, "it depends". There's no single right answer without considering the problem you're trying to solve.

In this specific case, I would consider making `Genre` its own model when and if you need to define genre-specific attributes that would not logically fit within the `Book` model. For example, if you're modeling a library, you might want to specify that some genres are appropriate for younger readers via a `child_friendly` attribute on the `Genre`. Or, if you're modeling a bookstore, the `Genre` might be used to specify what section of the store the book should be displayed in.

Answer (score 0):

My general rule of thumb is to avoid duplication in the tables whenever possible and to consider how likely and how easy it would be if I need to make changes to this property in the future.

**Creating a `genres` table**
This solution eliminates string duplication in your `books` table. It also makes changing the name of a genre a simple one-change fix, rather than a multi-change fix. You would just change the name once in the genre table rather than finding all records with the old genre name and updating them with the new name. Additionally, adding new properties to each genre (such as appropriate age range, or indicating whether it is a sub-genre of another) would be much easier as the table is already setup.

**ActiveRecord::Enum**
Another solution is to use ActiveRecord's [enum attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html). This has the same memory-saving and some of the ease-of-editing benefits of a `genres` table but with the added benefit of several helper-methods for setting and checking the genre value of a book instance, e.g. if you have a genre called 'thriller', using enum gives you the setter method `#thriller!` and the boolean-returning method `#thriller?` for free.

Answer (score -1):

If you have common fields with different model , in that case you should use `Single Table Inheritance` just by adding a type field in the table. This field contains the `model` name.

You can refer the below link for Single table inheritance
http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/